# Migration en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

Quiero realizar una migration a MySQL, cuando pongo en mi línea de comandos la instrucción **`php artisan migrate`** me sale el siguiente error en consola:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>                                                                                     could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
>   where t     able_schema = curso and table_name = migrations)
>
> In Connector.php line 67:
>                               could not find driver

En mi archivo .env tengo definido

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=curso
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: estas usando XAMPP?

Comment: Estoy usando MAMP

Comment: bueno ve a tu `php.ini` y encuentra una línea así: `;extension=pdo_mysql` y déjala así `extension=pdo_mysql` es decir quítale el punto y coma del inicio,. psterior reinicia tu servidor y trata de nuevo @Rebeca

Comment: pues el fallo ocurre por que no encuentra el driver de PDO, entonces prueba como te indico

Comment: al final coméntanos si sirvió o no

Comment: ya busque la línea que me comentas en el php.ini y esta sin comentar. No entiendo aún cual puede ser el problema.

Comment: si están sin comentar y aun así no lo encuentra entonces ve al directorio donde están los controladores y búscalo. si no están descargalo, copialo al directorio y reinicia el servidor.